# Как отследить вызов JS функций

Tags: javascript, flash

Здравствуйте! Такая ситуация, нужно обработать JS уведомления от flash приложения. Но очень трудно понять как эти уведомления называются (очень обфусцирован SWF), т.к. исходников нет, а при декомпиляции трудно искать такие вещи. Проект большой, просто на моём компе не поддерживается клиент для данного приложения, я делаю плагин для браузера, чтобы некоторые необходимые функции клиента были реализованы в браузере. Помогите пожалуйста, возможно ли отслеживать какие JS функции пытается вызвать flash?

**Собственно, я нашёл эту js функцию, посмотрев код клиента, но всё-таки интересно, неужели какая-то консоль JS не может отследить что вызывается функция, которой не существует. Или может в самом JS есть какие-то приёмы, чтобы если функция undefined вызывался какой-то catch с названием функции**

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы Вам помогли испортить, возможно, приложение того, кто даст ответ?

Comment: Мне не нравится, что если разговор заходит об SWF, то сразу все говорят о взломе и т.п. Каким образом я его испорчу по-вашему? В приложении есть стандартный уведомляльщик - вызывается javascript функция через Externalinterface, которая уведомляет о разных событиях клиент. Но клиент у меня не поддерживается, я хочу сделать, чтобы браузер слышал все эти уведомления и потом всем желающим отдать этот плагин. По сути так и устроен клиент этого flash приложения. Движок хрома с какими-то наверное коррективами, заточкой под приложение и js плагины для отслеживания js уведомлений.